# Is there a way to extract contents from AppleScript file without using AppleScript editor?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a bunch of applescript files I need to run but some that were running yesterday are not running today. Applescript is showing me this beautiful message.

[image]

**When this message is shown, console shows this message:
04/06/14 11:32:44,079 xpcd[324]: Info.plist does not contain an XPCService dictionary: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/XPCServices/SecurityAgent.xpc**

The problem is probably with applescript editor, because I have restored several copies of the script with different dates and none opens. Some other scripts open, but not this.

Is there a way t extract the contents of this file to a TXT so I can try to recreate the script?

thanks

NOTE: I have verified now that the scripts are not corrupted by running them from command line using osascript.

Comment: If you have Xcode you can try opening it with that?

Comment: Textmate can open binary SCPT files — it uses `osadecompile` transparently.

Comment: "Get script as text from scpt files?": https://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2007/Mar/msg00177.html

Comment: https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/reading-applescript-source-code-with-osadecompile/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** open a `.scpt` file with any editor! It is a compiled version of the script, not text, and it will not open with **any** editor.

Case in point, here is what happens when I try to view the file in Terminal...

[image: Viewing compiled applescript]

OSX comes with `osadecompile` that will extract the source code of a compiled script `.scpt` file.

Here is an example...

```
$ osadecompile args2.scpt 
on run argv
    set argc to 0
    try
        set argc to (count of argv)
    end try
    display dialog ("Argument Count: " & argc as string)
end run
```

Comment: That's a good tool to know about. However, this will not work with run-only compiled apps. Also, if apps aren't saved as run-only they will open right into the editor anyway.

Comment: TextMate *is* able to open `.scpt` files